# Calling the default constructor from another constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, call

I am trying to make the overloaded constructor call the default constructor, but it only gives me garbage numbers. What I want it to do is recognize if the date entered is invalid, and so default it to 1/1/2000.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "date.h"

using namespace std;

Date::Date () 
{
        month = 1;
        day = 1;
        year = 2000;
        monthName = "Jan ";
        format = 'D';
        valid = true;
}

Date::Date (int m, int d, int y)
{   
    valid = false;

        if (y > 0)
        {
            //January
            if (m == 1 && d >= 1 && d <= 31)
            {
                month = m; day = d; year = y; 
                monthName = "Jan "; valid = true;
            }

            //February
            else if (m == 2 && d >= 1 && d <= 28)
            {
                month = m; day = d; year = y; 
                monthName = "Feb "; valid = true;
            }

            //etc.
        }

    if (valid == false)
        Date ();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor can only be called when an object is first being *constructed*.  It is not a general-purpose function.

Your code here is doing that - constructing a new `Date`, but not doing anything with it.

```
Date ();
```

You can achieve what you want by *assigning* that new, default-constructed `Date`.

```
*this = Date();
```

*Edit: Be sure that `valid` is what you want it to be in this case.*

Comment: You are my hero and I love you.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf (a) I am not smart enough to figure out what member that would be.  I honestly tried.  (b) I would say it's very unclean and also the shortest path to *working*.  It's not *"the least clean"*, but I won't pain you with examples and I'm sure that you didn't downvote on that gut feeling.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Not very obvious from the OP's code, but `valid` is a data member. And should (no realistic alternative) presumably indicate whether the `Date` object represents valid arguments. However, it's set to `true` by the default constructor.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks for the clarification.  I figured that valid was a member, but did not want to speculate on its correct usage.

Answer (score 1):

First, in

```
Date ();
```

you are constructing a temporary, and discarding it. C++ does have low level facilities to call a constructor on existing storage, but an ordinary constructor call just creates a new object.

Also note that

```
if (valid == false)
```

can and should be more cleanly expressed as just

```
if( not valid )
```

or if you like symbolic operators,

```
if( !valid )
```

Now, the *intent* of the original code can be expressed

- by forwarding to a common constructor (a natural way would be by invoking and passing the result of a month name function), or
- by default-constructing first and then modifying, or
- by assigning a default-constructed instance.

These are in order of most clean to most unclean.

Do note that assigning a default-constructed instance, the most dirty option above, and doing nothing more, as suggested in another answer, will set the `valid` member to `true`, thus removing all information about the fact that the constructor arguments were invalid…

However, *none of these options are good*! For the intent, that of treating an argument error as a request for a default, is itself very ungood. Instead, when you detect an argument error, throw an exception or terminate, so that the client code will not have on hand a possibly unexpected object.

E.g., do

```
if( not valid ) { throw std::runtime_error( "Date::<init>: invalid args" ); }
```

Some folks prefer to use `std::logic_error` or `std::range_error`.

In passing, with Visual C++ force-include `<iso646.h>` to get support for the C++ keywords (less imprecisely, the reserved words) `and`, `or` and `not`.

---

Example of (not recommended! but least dirty of original intent implementations) common constructor approach:

```
class Date
{
private:
    int     day_;
    int     month_;
    int     year_;
    string  month_name_;
    bool    is_valid_;

    Date( int month, int day, int year, const string& month_name );

public:
    static
    auto month_name_for( int month, int day, int year )
        -> string;

    Date();
    Date( int month, int day, int year );
};

Date::Date( const int m, const int d, const int y, const string& month_name )
    : month_(         month_name == ""? 1     : m )
    , day_(           month_name == ""? 1     : d )
    , year_(          month_name == ""? 2000  : y )
    , month_name_(    month_name == ""? "Jan" : month_name )
    , is_valid_( month_name != "" )
{}

auto Date::month_name_for( const int m, const int d, const int y )
    -> string
{
    if( y > 0 )
    {
        if( m == 1 && 1 <= d && d <= 31 )           { return "Jan "; }
        const int days_in_feb = 28;     // TODO: correct for leap year
        if( m == 2 && 1 <= d && d <= days_in_feb )  { return "Feb "; }
        if( m == 3 && 1 <= d && d <= 31 )           { return "Mar "; }
        //etc.
    }
    return "";
}

Date::Date ()
    : Date( 0, 0, 0, "" )
{}

Date::Date( const int m, const int d, const int y )
    : Date( m, d, y, month_name_for( m, d, y ) )
{}
```

---

Example of each constructor ensuring a valid object (recommended):

```
class Date
{
private:
    int     day_;
    int     month_;
    int     year_;

public:
    static
    auto month_name_for( int month )
        -> string;
    static
    auto is_valid( int month, int day, int year )
        -> bool;

    Date();
    Date( int month, int day, int year );
};

auto Date::month_name_for( const int m )
    -> string
{
    static const string names[] = { "Jan", "Feb" };        // Etc.
    return (1 <= m && m <= 12? names[m-1] : "");
}

auto Date::is_valid( const int m, const int d, const int y )
    -> bool
{
    if( y > 0 )
    {
        if( m == 1 && 1 <= d && d <= 31 )           { return true; }
        const int days_in_feb = 28;     // TODO: correct for leap year
        if( m == 2 && 1 <= d && d <= days_in_feb )  { return true; }
        if( m == 3 && 1 <= d && d <= 31 )           { return true; }
        //etc.
    }
    return false;
}

Date::Date ()
    : Date( 1, 1, 2000 )
{}

Date::Date( const int m, const int d, const int y )
    : month_( m ), day_( d ), year_( y )
{
    if( not is_valid( m, d, y ) )
    {
        throw runtime_error( "Date::<init>: invalid arguments" );
    }
}
```